# NLog - header for each new file

Tags: nlog

I want NLog to print a header for every new file. I can only get it to do it on the 1st one, after that when the files reaches max size, the new file does not have the header.
What am I doing wrong?

```xml
<target name="DataLog" xsi:type="File" fileName="DCCData.log"
    layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.ffff}, ${message}"
    header="My header,"        
    archiveAboveSize="5024"
    archiveEvery="Day"
    archiveNumbering="Sequence"
    archiveFileName="DCCData_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-{##}.log"/>
```

Comment: Pogorman, I am using 3.1.0.0, but still has the problem.Can you able to fix it?

Comment: Sorry - I don't contribute to NLog, but I can say for sure that the issue was not present in 3.0

Comment: Well, I do small experiment with latest NLog but does not work with Daily archive...Interesting

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it was a bug that that has been fixed in 3.0
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/245